# Which is better, Enumerable.Empty<T> or new[0]?

Tags: c#

These are the same:

```
IEnumerable<string> i;
i = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
i = new string[0];
```

So, which to use?

I think the first communicates intent more clearly, but it is bigger and a bit noisier, not to mention ugly in the debugger. The second is also more efficient in memory and CPU, if I'm reading Reflector right.

I'm leaning towards the `new type[0]`, but wanted to know what you all think.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Enumerable.Empty<T>` caches the creation of the empty array, so the same array will be always be returned, while the second statement creates a new array with each call.

I would tend to `Enumerable.Empty<T>`, as it shows the intention of the programmer more clearly, and also because using an explicit array creation because of memory usage is premature optimization in a managed program, as the runtime will almost always allocate more than necessary memory to the process anyway.

Answer (score 8):

The difference in terms of performance/memory usage is incredibly negligible in this situation, so that would not be my deciding factor.

I would personally use `Enumerable.Empty`, mainly because it very clearly describes the developer intent.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like `Enumerable.Empty` delegates to `EmptyEnumerable` which returns an array of length 0.  But it returns the same one every time, and keeps that empty array alive forever.