# MVC Core 1.0 NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, razor-2

My code is trying to enumerate over a (currently empty) list of movies. When it gets to the `ForEach` loop it blows up with the stated error.

I would think it would just not iterate (moveNext()). How can I fix this behavior so that it will just display an empty list when the collection is blank

```
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal
@using x.Models
@model IEnumerable<x.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MovieView";
}

<h2>MovieView</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="List">Movie List</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (Movie item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: make sure you create an empty instance of the list before it is sent to the view, So check your controller for the values of the list and make sure it is not null.

Comment: Agree with JustLearning.  Probably need to add vm.Movie = new List<theType>();

Comment: I would lean towards Enumberable.Empty<T>() more than new List<T>(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319930/which-is-better-enumerable-emptyt-or-new0